# Keep old value(re-populate old value) of a dropdown when redirecting or refreshing form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I'm using laravel form in a blade file. I used validation for the form and when submitting if there is a validation error the from will refresh and redirect the same form page. I want to keep the entered data as the same way after redirecting. Normal input fields are keeping the value, but the dropdown doesn't work in the same way. (I tried on multiple answers as this same issue in earlier questions. Didn't work).

Here is part of my code and where the issues is,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="block uppercase text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold">{{ __('Phone Number') }} 
</label>
 <input type="phone" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" value="{{old('phone_number')}}" class="form-control">
</div>

//here is the dropdown and it has the issue
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="block uppercase text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold col-form-label">{{ __('Country') }}</label>
          <select name="country" id="countrylist" class="form-control js-example-basic-single" value="{{old('country')}}">
            @include('layouts.country-list')
          </select>
    </div>
```

in the upper part, the phone number is keeping the old value, but the country dropdown list doesn't. I also used `value="{{old('country')}}"` as the same way in other input fields. when redirecting it turns into the default value again. So how to keep or repopulate the value in the dropdown?

(Hope my explanation is clear. Please inform me if it's not)

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly select an item (`option`) from a `select` element you should explicitly mark the respective `option` element as `selected` where the old input of that `select` element equals the `option`'s value.

here's an example:

```
// say we have the following items
$options = ['red' => '#FF0000', 'green' => '#00FF00', 'blue' => '#0000FF'];
```

We want to populate a dropdown from the above `$options` array while keeping the latest selected option (if exists):

```
<select name="colors">
    <option value="">choose</option>
    @foreach($options as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('colors') == $key ? 'selected':''}}>{{ $value }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Based on the above sample, if the user chooses `green` option  which has the `green` key (from `$options` array) then that option will automatically be selected on next page load (if a validation error occurs obviously).